# Find a polygon different from a square with area 1 and perimeter 4.

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry

Find a polygon which have the area and perimeter as 1 and 4 respectively.

**EXCEPT FOR A UNIT SQUARE.**

PLEASE HELP ME

> I have tried a lot...
> But none of my method works, it's a big headache someone please help me!

**NB: Polygon need not be a Regular polygon.**

Comment: Take any regular polygon which inscribed circle has radius $1/2$.

Comment: Deform the unit square into a rhombus.

Comment: There is an isoperimetric inequality for polygons. For any $n$-gon with perimeter $L$ and area $\Delta$, one has $L^2 \ge (4n\tan\frac{\pi}{n})\Delta$ with equality iff the $n$-gon is regular. In order for $L = 4$ and $\Delta = 1$, you need $n > 4$ or you will get the unit square. A simple way is pick a square of size $s$, cut off a right angled triangle of side $t,t,\sqrt{2}t$ from a corner to get a pentagon. You will get two equations in $s,t$ which isn't that hard to solve.

Comment: Cutting two opposite corners of square $a$ size, you'll get polygon with perimeter $4a-4b+2b\sqrt{2}$ and area $a^2-b^2$. To make perimeter 4, and area 1, one must take $a=(8\sqrt{2}-3)/7$, $b=(6\sqrt{2}-4)/7$.

Comment: Other solution based on Michael Hoppe idea. One can take circle of radius 1/2, circumscribe regular triangle, then cut corners in such way that polygon stays circumscribed and perimeter approaches 4.

Comment: Seems that it can not be convex - so it has to be a star polygon. Did you try a star polygon?

Comment: @Moti it can be convex. it can even be a tangential polygon with inradius 1/2.

Comment: @JohnDouma That deformation will change the shape's area.

Comment: @Saeed Shearing does not change area.

Comment: @Saeed The problem with the deformation is that the perimeter changes.

Comment: Do not vandalize your question when you have received an answer! @101

Answer (score 5):

I guess the tricky part of the problem is the emphasis on avoiding the unit square. It's a bit misleading!

Start from the unit square and you can make simple modifications to it. Here is one possible solution:

[image]

An arbitrary triangle has been cut off a corner of the square and pasted on a side. Dashed lines show the square before the modification.

Verification of satisfaction of requirements of the problem by this image is left as an exercise to the interested reader.